# What is the name of this valve?

Tags: valve, sprinkler-system, winterizing

[image] We are winterizing our sprinkler system.Does anyone know the name of this valve? Were looking for a replacement. Thanks

Comment: No, you took the valve off. It might be a backflow preventer

Comment: How was it hooked up?  Try taking pictures before dismantling everything.

Comment: Looks like a plain old valve.  One end is to connect to standard threaded brass/iron pipe, while the other end is to connect to a flex pipe/hose.  The thing on the side is where a screwdriver or an (absent) knob fits to turn things on/off.  It is odd, however, to have something so small in a sprinkler system.

Comment: Depending on the style of valve mechanism it's either a "ball valve" or a "needle valve".

Comment: Seems to be a ball valve from a vacuum breaker/backflow preventer. It's probably the valve that you hook the air compressor up to blow out/winterize the system.

Comment: Your hand is so clean and soft and the nail looks like it is manicured.   Who is doing the work?

Comment: @Ruskes - *Is* this a valve, is a good question.

Comment: "Bob". I'd say it's name is Bob...

Answer (score 1):

Compression (bottom) to flare (top). Doesn't really matter what type it is, just its fittings is your concern, and their size : yours says 1/8".

---

Shown: 1/4" Flare x 1/4" MIPS **Straight Needle Valve**

[image]

https://www.plumbingsupply.com/flarefittings.html#straight

Comment: If possible, ditch flare asap. Like, if you have to redo the end on the pipe too, then just switch to all compression. Doing flares sucks. The only place it still belongs these days is in RVs (compression doesn't like vibrations).